# How to calculate clustering entropy - example and my solution given but is it correct?

Tags: algorithm, math, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, entropy

I would like to calculate entropy of this example scheme

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

[image]

Equation of entropy

Then the entropy is (the first line)

[image]

**So entropy is for this scheme**

```
For the first cluster - ( (5/6)*Log(5/6) + (1/6)*Log(1/6) ) 
For the second cluster  - ( (1/6)*Log(1/6) + (1/6)*Log(1/6) + (4/6)*Log(4/6) )
For the third cluster  - ( (2/5)*Log(2/5) + (3/5)*Log(3/5) )
```

Final entropy is :

```
 FirtCluster_Entropy + SecondCluster_Entropy  + ThirdCluster_Entropy
```

Am i correct?

Comment: In what way is this a programming question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: I vote to move this question to Cross-Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Very close!  For the total entropy of the clustering you need need to weight each cluster's entropy by its relative weight.  Please see my answer to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780505/159646.

Also this should probably be posted to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: I also told you you need to weight clusters ... it would be good if you take the answers you get more seriously instead of reasking again and again.